# How do I draw gridlines using abline() that are behind the data?

Tags: r, plot

When I draw grid lines on a plot using `abline()` the grid lines are drawn over the data.

Is there a way to draw the `abline()` lines behind the data? I feel this would look better.

Example:

```
x <- seq(0, 10)
y <- x
plot(x, y, col = 'red', type = 'o', lwd = 3, pch = 15)
abline(h = seq(0, 10, .5), col = 'lightgray', lty = 3)
abline(v = seq(0, 10, .5), col = 'lightgray', lty = 3)
```

The plot produced has the gray grid lines going over the data (red line). I would like the red line to be on top of the gray lines.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The `panel.first` argument of `plot()` can take a list or vector of functions so you can put your `abline()` calls in there.

```
plot(1:4, panel.first = 
       c(abline(h = 1:4, lty = 2, col = 'grey') 
        ,abline(v = 1:4, lty = 2, col = 'grey')))
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer. I already tell I'm going to be using panel.first a lot in the future.

Comment: how to do the same for boxplot?

Comment: This should be a new question, not a comment. But see methods below since boxplot doesn't rely on plot.

Answer (score 16):

Use `plot()` to set up the plotting window, but use `type = "n"` to not plot any data. Then do your `abline()` calls, or use `grid()`, and then plot the data using whatever low-level function is appropriate (here `points()` is fine).

```
x <- seq(0, 10)
y <- x
plot(x, y, type = "n")
abline(h = seq(0, 10, .5), col = 'lightgray', lty = 3)
abline(v = seq(0, 10, .5), col = 'lightgray', lty = 3)
points(x, y, col = 'red', type = 'o', lwd = 3, pch = 15)
```

or

```
## using `grid()`
plot(x, y, type = "n")
grid()
points(x, y, col = 'red', type = 'o', lwd = 3, pch = 15)
```

See `?grid` for details of how to specify the grid as per your `abline()` version.

Answer (score 8):

Plot first with type="n" to establish coordinates. Then put in the grid lines, then plot again with your regular plot type:

```
plot(x, y, col = 'red', type = 'n', lwd = 3, pch = 15)
abline(h = seq(0, 10, .5), col = 'lightgray', lty = 3)
abline(v = seq(0, 10, .5), col = 'lightgray', lty = 3)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x, y, col = 'red', type = 'o', lwd = 3, pch = 15)
```

I admit that I have always thought the name for that `par` parameter was "backwards."

Comment: backwards, and not really needed if you plot the data using `points()` for example.

Comment: I didn't realize that 'type' argument was available in `points`.

Comment: It's not necessary with points().  I think Gavin was implying that you would make your initial type = 'n' plot() call as you did but then just change your last line to points( instead of plot(.  Then the par() call isn't needed.  BTW, type is available in points and lines I believe, I know that I sometimes want both and just call lines() with type = 'b'.

Comment: I understood his point. I was just explaining why I didn't use two calls to points and lines.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of creating grid lines is to set `tck=1` when plotting or in the `axis` function (you may still want to plot the points using `points` after creating the grid lines.