# Plotting a grid behind data, not in front in R

Tags: r, plot

I like to produce my own grid lines when plotting so I can control tick marks, etc. and I am struggling with this with the 'hist' plotting routine.

```
    hist(WindSpeed, breaks=c(0:31), freq=TRUE, col="blue", xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="Wind Speed (m/s)",main="Foo", cex.main=1.5, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1, tck=1, font.lab=2)
    axis(1, tck=1, ,col.ticks="light gray")
    axis(1, tck=-0.015, col.ticks="black")
    axis(2, tck=1, col.ticks="light gray", lwd.ticks="1")
    axis(2, tck=-0.015)
    minor.tick(nx=5, ny=2, tick.ratio=0.5)
    box()
```

Plot:
[image]

I have then just been able to use the 'lines' or 'points' command to replot the data over top for other types of plots, but with the histogram its not so easy.

Any help would be great.

I added my code below and image based upon John's response...

I added my code below and image based upon John's response...

```
hist(WindSpeed, breaks=30, freq=TRUE, col="blue", xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="Wind Speed (m/s)",main="Foo", cex.main=1.5, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1, font.lab=2)
axis(1, tck=1, col.ticks="light gray")
axis(1, tck=-0.015, col.ticks="black")
axis(2, tck=1, col.ticks="light gray", lwd.ticks="1")
axis(2, tck=-0.015)
minor.tick(nx=5, ny=2, tick.ratio=0.5)
box()
hist(WindSpeed, add=TRUE, breaks=30, freq=TRUE, col="blue", xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="Wind Speed (m/s)", main="Foo", cex.main=1.5, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1, font.lab=2)
```

[image]

Comment: You can shorten your second hist command up a lot because when adding it to the existing one you don't need to set any of the axis properties and labels again.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is relatively easy.

Generate the histogram but don't plot it.

```
h <- hist(y, plot = FALSE)
```

Now generate your base plot... I've added some features to make it look more like a standard historgram

```
plot(h$mids, h$counts, ylim = c(0, max(h$counts)), xlim = range(h$mids)*1.1, 
    type = 'n', bty = 'n', xlab = 'y', ylab = 'Counts', main = 'Histogram of y')
```

add your grid

```
grid()
```

add your histogram

```
hist(y, add = TRUE)
```

Or, as I discovered through this process... you can do it even easier

```
hist(y)
grid()
hist(y, add = TRUE, col = 'white')
```

This last method is just redrawing the histogram over the grid.

Comment: Nice. Your last method's simple and effective. I especially like that it doesn't require precalculation of the limits of the plotting area!

Comment: The add=TRUE call is what I was missing...thanks John...simple and sweet...I added my code and result

Comment: Actually, @John, `panel.first` works here too, just as in your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7264055/210673

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. I didn't bother including it because my plot command was already pretty long.  plot.histogram should really take a panel.first argument.

Answer (score 32):

Actually, R has a way to do this!  It's the `panel.first` argument to `plot.default`, which `hist` calls to do most of the work.  It takes an expression which is evaluated "after the plot axes are set up but before any plotting takes place. This can be useful for drawing background grids or scatterplot smooths," to quote from `?plot.default`.

```
hist(WindSpeed, breaks=c(0:31), freq=TRUE, col="blue", xaxt="n", yaxt="n", 
     xlab="Wind Speed (m/s)", main="Foo", 
     cex.main=1.5, cex.axis=1, cex.lab=1, tck=1, font.lab=2,
     panel.first={
        axis(1, tck=1, col.ticks="light gray")
        axis(1, tck=-0.015, col.ticks="black")
        axis(2, tck=1, col.ticks="light gray", lwd.ticks="1")
        axis(2, tck=-0.015)
        minor.tick(nx=5, ny=2, tick.ratio=0.5)
        box()
 })
```

See [How do I draw gridlines using abline() that are behind the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7263743/210673) for another question that uses this method.

Comment: Thanks. I found that the syntax of this answer worked better than the solution provided in the suggested other link here.

Answer (score 7):

In R, order matters when you plot. As you've discovered, adding things to a plot adds on top of what you've plotted before. So we need a way to plot the grid *first* and then the histogram. Try something like this:

```
plot(1:10,1:10,type = "n")
grid(10,10)
hist(rnorm(100,5,1),add = TRUE)
```

[image]

I haven't recreated your example, since it isn't reproducible, but this general idea should work. But the key idea is to create an empty plot with the correct dimensions using the `type = "n"` option to `plot`, then add the grid, then add the histogram using the `add = TRUE` argument.

Note that the `add` argument is actually for `plot.histogram`, `hist` passes it along via `...`.

Answer (score 4):

The base graphics solution suggested by @joran is fine.  Alternatives:

```
d <- data.frame(x=rnorm(1000))    

library(lattice)
histogram(~x,data=d,panel=function(...) {
     panel.grid(...)
     panel.histogram(...) } 
)
```

Or:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x,data=d,geom="histogram",binwidth=0.1)+theme_bw()+
   labs(x="Wind speed", y="Frequency")
```

(But of course you will have to learn all the details of adjusting labels, titles, etc. ... I'm not actually sure how to do titles in `ggplot` ...)

Answer (score 3):

Another methods for grid lines in background:

A)

```
hist( y, panel.first=grid() )  # see: help( plot.default )
box()
```

B)

```
plot.new()                     # new empty plot
nv <- length( pretty(x) ) - 1  # number of vertical grid lines (or set by hand)
nh <- length( pretty(y) ) - 1  # number of horizontal grid lines (or set by hand)
grid( nx = nv, ny = nh )       # preplot grid lines
par( new = TRUE )              # add next plot
plot( x, y )                   # plot or hist, etc
box()                          # if plot hist
```

Arbitrary lines in background with abline:

C)

[How do I draw gridlines using abline() that are behind the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263743/how-do-i-draw-gridlines-using-abline-that-are-behind-the-data?noredirect=1&lq=1)

D)

```
# first, be sure there is no +/-Inf, NA, NaN in x and y
# then, make the container plot with two invisible points:
plot( x = range( pretty( x ) ), y = range( pretty( y ) ), type = "n", ann = FALSE )
abline( h = hlines, v = vlines )  # draw lines. hlines, vlines: vectors of coordinates
par( new = TRUE )                 # add next plot. It is not necessary with points, lines, segments, ...
plot( x, y )                      # plot, hist, etc
box()                             # if plot hist
```