# R: plot line segment behind points in R

Tags: r, plot, beeswarm

I'm using the 'beeswarm' package and want to plot an abline behind my points. The code below will plot the line on top of my points.

```
library(beeswarm)
testdf<-data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),b=c(1,2,3,1,4,6,1,3,4))
beeswarm(b ~ a,data=testdf,col="red",bg="red",pch=21)
abline(3,0)
```

I know this question has been answered for plots just using base R (such as here: [How do I draw gridlines using abline() that are behind the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263743/how-do-i-draw-gridlines-using-abline-that-are-behind-the-data)), but these solutions when applied to my data just create two plots one with an abline and one with the beeswarm plot.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a second call to `beeswarm` at the end with the parameter `add = TRUE`.

I've made the dots bigger in this example so you can clearly see them plotted over the `abline`

```
library(beeswarm)
testdf<-data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),b=c(1,2,3,1,4,6,1,3,4))
beeswarm(b ~ a,data=testdf,col="red",bg="red",pch=21, cex = 5)
abline(3,0)
beeswarm(b ~ a,data=testdf,col="red",bg="red",pch=21, cex = 5, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: add = TRUE is the magic I was missing! Thank you for your time, appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `abline` call to `panel.first` within the `beeswarm` function

```r
library(beeswarm)

testdf<-data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),b=c(1,2,3,1,4,6,1,3,4))

beeswarm(b ~ a,data=testdf,col="red",bg="red",pch=21, panel.first = abline(3,0))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>