# How to push an abline grid to the background in a plot?

Tags: r, plot, time-series, grid, abline

I'm trying to plot a grid for a time series plot using `abline()`. It works fine, but I'm not able to draw the grid lines in the background: they are above the time series line.

I'm using the following code:

```
options(repr.plot.width=15, repr.plot.height=10)
par(cex=1.5)

plot(Serie_PIB_NO_ajustados_hasta_2018,
    xlab="Tiempo", #Título de los ejes
    ylab="Miles de millones de €", 
    main="PIB pm Demanda España (datos no ajustados de estacionalidad y calendario)",
    col="blue",
    lwd = 3,
    xlim = c(1995, 2020),
    ylim = c(0, 350),
    xaxp = c(1995, 2019, 8)) 

lines(Serie_PIB_NO_ajustados_2019,
      col="green", lwd=3)

abline(h = c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350), col = "grey")
abline(v = c(1995, 1998, 2001, 2004, 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016, 2019), col = "grey")
```

To get this graph:
[image]
(You could see that the grid lines are above the time series lines).

I've tried to solve the problem using `panel.first` and `tck` options, as suggested in several related questions. But they don't work for me.

Data may be downloaded from this [link](https://ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30680&L=0).

Comment: what kind of object is `Serie_PIB_NO_ajustados_hasta_2018`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I draw gridlines using abline() that are behind the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263743/how-do-i-draw-gridlines-using-abline-that-are-behind-the-data). There are more options than using `panel.first`. If it doesn't work, please update your answer with some data.

Comment: @rawr it's a `ts` object. I've created it using `ts()` function.

Comment: @harre I've already tried that solution, but `panel.first` seems to not work in my case.

Comment: `plot(ts(1:5), panel.first = grid())` works so theres not much we can do for you without other details

Comment: @harre I'd rather using `abline()` because `grid()` has problem with adjusting the vertical lines to a time series plot ticks.

Comment: Please post some data according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and explain more in depth what you have tried.

Comment: @rawr I've already tried `tck` too. It doesn't work either.

Comment: With base graphics, elements are added in the sequence of the commands. Use a `plot(NA, ...)` command to set up the plot, but not add any lines. Then use the `abline()` (it can take both h= and v= in a single call), then add the two sets of lines with two `lines()` calls.

Comment: @dcarlson Ooohhh this is totally correct. Thanks a lot! You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
plot(NA, xlab="Tiempo", #Título de los ejes
    ylab="Miles de millones de €", 
    main="PIB pm Demanda España (datos no ajustados de estacionalidad y calendario)",
    xlim = c(1995, 2020),
    ylim = c(0, 350),
    xaxp = c(1995, 2019, 8)) 

abline(h = c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350), col = "grey")
abline(v = c(1995, 1998, 2001, 2004, 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016, 2019), col = "grey") 

lines(Serie_PIB_NO_ajustados_hasta_2018, col="blue", lwd = 3)
lines(Serie_PIB_NO_ajustados_2019, col="green", lwd=3)
```